# Can I check in code to another project in TFS 2013?

Tags: tfs, checkin

I'm writing code in a TFS 2013 Project. I'd like to check it into a different Project on the same server. Can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Sure. Have you tried to do it? What problems are you encountering?

Comment: Haven't tried it. TFS draws pretty firm lines between projects for many things, so thought I should ask first. Thanks Daniel

Comment: Can't do it, regardless of security/authentication/group membership settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not directly check in the code to another project, you need to add the code file to another project first for source control, then check in the code  changes.

In visual studio Team Explorer:

1. Connect To TFS project 1, configure the workspace and map source
   code to local **folder1**. Open the **folder1** in windows explorer.
2. Connect To project 2, configure the workspace and map source code to
   local **folder2**. Open the **folder2** in windows explorer.
3. Copy the code file which you want to check into another project (eg,
   project 2 here ) from **folder1** to **folder2**, then the system
   will detected the new added files under **Pending Changes** >
   **Excluded changes**.
4. Click the `Detected` link to Promote the new added files.
5. Check in the files to Project 2

Refer to these articles for more information : [Add files to the server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/add-files-server)
and [Check in your work to the team's codebase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/check-your-work-team-codebase)

---

**UPDATE:**

You can link to the WI in the same collection, but cannot link to the WI which in another collection.

That means, if the team projects are in the same collection, then you can link the WI (associate with the changeset) which belongs to another project directly.

[image]

Comment: Thank Andy! Our process will be to include a link to the WI on the other project.

Comment: @MitchNewland If the "**other**" project is in the same collection with your current project, then you can link the WI directly when check in the changes. You cannot link to the WI which in another collection.

Comment: Correct. Same collection, different project/team is the only thing that works.